# Chart with two formats

Tags: excel, charts, format

This is odd . . .
I have a Chart with ten sets of "x-y" data.

But now I have tried to put in two more - and Excel ignores the first column which it regards as sequential, i.e.

Instead of

```
    4.41    1103

    6.91    1262

    7.06    1275

    7.89    1329
```

it treats it as

```
    1   1103

    2   1262

    3   1275

    4   1329
```

How do I prevent this ?

Comment: Show the series function used in the chart.

Comment: Sorry; I don't understand.